# Usb headset trouble

Tags: sound, usb

I'm having troubles with my usb headset.

```
felipe@ubuntu:~/builds$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no se encontraron tarjetas de sonido...
felipe@ubuntu:~/builds$ sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for felipe: 
**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
Home directory not accessible: Permiso denegado
tarjeta 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 3: Headset [HP Digital Stereo Headset], dispositivo 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
```

I have tried editing /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
felipe@ubuntu:~/builds$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd-hda-intel index=-2
```

Works, but 1 of 3 boot recognize the card...

The trouble is not all aplication use the usb headset, for example Half Life 2 and audacity and firefox, so because of that i had changed the alsa-base.conf, making the usb card index to 0 to be the prefered card number 0 and to get ALL of my apps using my usb headset... but this not work always